# Converting [NSObject, AnyObject] to [String, AnyObject] in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, casting

I have the following line which used to work in iOS 8 in Swift.

```
 let placemark = placemarks![0] as? CLPlacemark

 let destinationPlacemark = MKPlacemark(

     coordinate: placemark!.location!.coordinate, 
     addressDictionary: placemark?.addressDictionary

 )
```

but now it gives me the following exception:

> Cannot convert value of type '[NSObject : AnyObject]?' to expected
>   argument type '[String : AnyObject]?'

How can I do that?

Comment: Try casting `placemark?.addressDictionary as? [String:AnyObject]`

Comment: That did the trick! Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Since it works,i will post an answer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to cast the type to `[String : AnyObject]`

```
placemark?.addressDictionary as? [String:AnyObject]
```